# How to pass multiple IDs to visual flow sobject collection variable from javascript button

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

I'm constructing the following url and then calling it in my javascript button, however, the sobject collection variable is not being populated.

https://cs25.salesforce.com/flow/Field_Support_Line_Item_Status_Update?a9614000000TN20,a9614000000TN21&retURL=/a8K14000000KzBy

Here is the code that creates the url above:

```
SelectedLineItems = selected.join(',');
      url="/flow/Field_Support_Line_Item_Status_Update?" + SelectedLineItems + "&retURL=/{!Field_Support__c.Id}";
      window.location = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning that concatenated string of IDs to a variable in the flow. Flow params align to get params, so you need to do something like `/flow/myFlow?myparam=myValue`.